# Размытие форм SVG при прохождении по траектории обрезки (clipPath)

Tags: svg, svg-animation, svg-filter

Пример ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел бы сохранить фиксированную область в середине, через которую анимируются
круги svg.

Большинство примеров, которые я видел, включают какое-то слияние, в результате которого видны как исходный круг, так и размытая версия.
Примерно так:

```
<clipPath id="top-mask">
  <rect id="top-mask-rect" x="0" y="-100" width="100" height="100" />
</clipPath>

<filter id="top-blur" x="-200%" y="-200%" width="500%" height="500%">
  <feimage xlinkHref="url(#top-mask)" result="mask" />
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" result="blur" />

  <feComposite in2="mask" in="blur" operator="in" result="comp" />

  <feMerge result="merge">
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    <feMergeNode in="comp" />
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Круги накладываются поверх слегка размытой версии. Моим следующим шагом было удалить `feComposite` и вместо этого применить `clipPath` к обоим `feMergeNode`, что вообще не сработало.

Как правильно подойти к этой проблеме?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Blurring svg shapes as they pass through clip path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47984590/7394871) от участника  [@rbhalla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330719/rbhalla).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/47984590/7394871

Comment: сколько надо ждать чтобы ассоциация заработала?

Comment: @Danis Если Вы спрашиваете, когда появится синяя табличка на enSO, то это будет после обновления. К сожалению это делается до сих пор вручную сотрудником SO Николаем. Как только он сделает проводку ассоциации, а сотрудники enSO  на своей стороне, что-то там сделают, тогда и появится синий шильдик. Поэтому я жду накопления 30 -50 штук, чтобы не дергать ребят по мелочам.

Answer (score 3):

Все не так уж и элементарно. Чтобы это сработало, вам нужно немного сложить эти элементы друг на друга.
Вам понадобится маска, чтобы показать не размытый объект снаружи, и фильтр, чтобы показать его внутри обозначенной области.
Обеим нужны единицы, определенные как `userSpaceOnUse`.

```css
#moving {
  animation: move 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
    0% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) }
   50% { transform: translate(300px, 0px) }
  100% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     height="300" width="500">
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask"
        maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <rect id="still" x="150" y="0" width="200" height="300" fill="black" />
  </mask>
    <filter id="blur" x="150" y="0" width="200" height="300"
            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask)">
    <circle id="moving" r="60" cy="150" cx="100" fill="blue" />
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#blur)">
    <use xlink:href="#moving" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Интересно, как работает фильтр. Кажется, что объект обрезается до применения размытия, что приводит к размытию около границы обозначенной области вместо резкого обрезания. Я не уверен, назвать это ошибкой или ожидаемым поведением. (Быстрый тест показал это как для Firefox, так и для Chrome.)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47993239/7394871) от участника  [@ccprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996779/ccprog).</sub>